# Spring @RequestParam for every request

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

Is it possible to put `@RequestParam String key` just only in one place, to not write it in each controller?

Comment: No. What's the concrete problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I would like to require `@RequestParam String key` in each API call, less boilerplate code

Comment: Why would each and every API call need to send the same request param? What is it? My guess is that this is some kind of authentication token, that should be in a header, not in a request param. Even if it's in a request param, you probably don't want to handle it in each and every controller, but in a central place, like a filter or an interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Pojo object which include `key` property, and add this object or a sub class to Controller instead of explicitly adding a String parameter

Comment: How can I use request body when use GET?